# How to retrieve an image URL from another page, when the relative URL where the image is found, is stored in a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a relative URL string stored in a cookie i.e. `foo/bar/abc`.

I want to return the full URL of an image found on this page as a string within a JavaScript variable. The image on this other page has the unique class `.image`.

Both the URL where this variable will be created and the URL stored in the cookie are on the same domain.

The cookie name is `URLForImage`

How do I go about getting the URL of the image on another page as a variable using JavaScript / jQuery?

So far I have the script to amend content on the page where the variable needs to be created. I don't know how to pull the URL from the cookie, and then retrieve attributes from elements on this page (to define `ImageUrl`):

```
<script>
var ImageUrl = ;
$( ".newimage" ).css("background-image", "url(ImageUrl)");
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: `Both the URL where this variable will be created and the URL stored in the cookie are on the same domain` If that's the case it would make more sense (and be a lot easier) to just read the cookie in JS directly...

Comment: On the same domain, but not the same page. I still don't know how to read  attributes of an element from another page (the URL of which can be found within the cookie, and the element class is known and fixed).

Comment: That's still fine, you can read the cookie in JS. Loading an entire HTML page to get one specific string within it is really not a good idea.

Comment: I haven't said I want to load the entire page, just that all the information i have is the URL of the page and the element class. I just don't know how to read the cookie is JS to get the attributes of an element that is on that URL. How can the attributes of an img element on another URL be read, without this being loaded then?

Comment: Do I need to use .load() to get at the element? I have tried this but still can't understand the syntax to find the background-image SRC?